# How can I sink the output of an Azure Data Factory activity to a SQL database?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In my pipeline, I have a Lookup activity, which outputs it's data to an Azure Function activity.

I'd like to save the result of the Azure Function activity to a SQL Database.

The only activity I can see which writes to a SQL Database (or other Dataset) is the Copy Data activity, but that doesn't seem like it can take the Azure Function activity's output as it's input.

My "ideal solution" would by to have the inverse of the Lookup activity that takes an input from some other activity and sinks it to a dataset.

It seems a little weird to me that there is a generic Lookup activity to read data from a dataset, but no generic "Store" activity to write data to a dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [supported connectors of copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview),azure function connector is not supported.You could adopt a workaround that using Azure Blob Storage as temporary space.

Process the data in azure function and output it to [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob).

Configure [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage) as source and SQL Database as sink in copy activity.

Comment: So you're suggesting the Azure Function invoked by the pipeline writes to a Blob Storage, and the Copy Data activity then reads from this same Blob storage?

I was hoping I could keep my Azure Function from needing to connect to any datasets.

Comment: @KevBelisle Yeah,that's what i said.I understand you want to connect azure function activity with copy activity directly,am i right? But it is not supported. The solution i suggested still could keep all activities in one pipeline and executed in the order.

Comment: @KevBelisle Also, please refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup.

Comment: @KevBelisle Hi,if my answer helps you,would you please accept it?Thanks a lot.